# How to scroll right/left with Karate UI?

Tags: user-interface, scroll, karate

I'm not able to scroll with Karate UI. My page only shows half of the grid, i need to scroll all the way to the right, and validate the data, clicking is not needed. I have tried all the friendly locators, mouse operations, special keys. Not moving at all.

- mouse().move(100, 200).go()
- scroll('#myBtn')
- rightOf()
- input('#someInput', 'test input' + Keys.RIGHT)

What else i can use?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be very easy by calling [`scrollIntoView()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp) on the DOM.

```
* script('#myBtn', '_.scrollIntoView()')
```

Comment: this script is not compiling, maybe i have older version of karate, newer versions are not approved in the company yet. is there any other way to write this script in Karate? if i change script to eval is compiling but not scrolling...

Comment: @Arilay sorry you have to upgrade

Comment: Hi Peter, to which versions do i need to update? i had 0.9.5 apache, core, junit4. I have changed to 0.9.6.RC3 apache, core, junit4, but im getting missing steps for * script('#myBtn', '_.scrollIntoView()') line, and my assertions and if conditions are failing now.. Please suggest

Comment: @Arilay try reading the docs. still stuck ? follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: assertions and if conditions are working after changing exists to optional. Not the scroll yet, will submit a ticket. Thank you